# Right version of the android google play services

Tags: android

I'm building an android app to store a text file in the google drive.According to my perspective, the code is OK. But when I put the app level dependency of the google play-services, it throws an error in the app level version dependency. Due to this reason, I cannot sync the gradle. I think the error is with the version numbers. 
here is the play service dependency I put
"compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'"

And this is the dependency that shows as an error when I put the above dependency 
 "compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'"

Here is my app level graddle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.xxxxx.calllogtogoogledrive"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

Here is the project level gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to change your build.gradle like this;

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com" }
    }
```

Remove `jcenter()` add this.

Comment: The compilation error is gone .There is a run time error now.